# I getting a 'Reverse for 'views.mainPage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.4

I getting a 'Reverse for 'views.mainPage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.'

mainPage method in /django_crm/crm/views.py

```
@login_required
def mainPage(request):
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'user': request.user,
            })  

    return render_to_response('mainPage.html', variables)
```

and /django_crm/django_crm/templates/mainPage.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% url 'crm.views.mainPage' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Error...

```
Reverse for ''crm.views.mainPage'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% load url from future %}` if you are using django < 1.5

Or

Remove quotes from url tag.

> Changed in Django 1.5: The first parameter used not to be quoted,
>   which was inconsistent with other template tags. Since Django 1.5, it
>   is evaluated according to the usual rules: it can be a quoted string
>   or a variable that will be looked up in the context.